# Syncronize mouse sensitivity Ubuntu 14.04/Windows 7 dual boot?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mouse

How would I do this? It's driving me quite nuts getting used to the Ubuntu 14.04 sensitivity(I have it set to lowest) and my Windows 7 one. It's.. Close, but a bit different, and it's causing me to misclick a bunch in Windows 7 when working there.

Is there any way to completely sync the two sensitivities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to sync your mouse settings.

Your best shot is to just increase your ubuntu mouse sensitivity to match that of Windows 7's lowest and get used to it.

Sorry, I wish there was more to it but you simply can't. :(